# Probability to get a 1 in 5 rolls 3 or more times

Tags: probability, dice

If I roll a dice 5 times, what is the probability to get 3 or more ones?

That is, to roll a one three or more times?

Because I think it's near 0.05:

$ \binom{5}{3} \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^3 = 0.046 $

But [this guy](https://youtu.be/c_tYZxQLoDA?feature=shared&t=81) sustains it is near `0.03`.

Comment: In `R`: `1 - pbinom(2, 5, 1/6)` equals `0.03549383`. A quick simulation is in excellent agreement.

Comment: @COOLSerdash The correct formula is `1 - pbinom(2, 5, 1/6) - pbinom(1, 5, 1/6) - pbinom(0, 5, 1/6)`, right? We don't want 1 one and we don't want 0 ones either, right?

Answer (score 2):

Your math is not right. You are missing part of the [binomial probability formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). The correct calculation would be
$$P(X = 3) = \binom{5}{3}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^3\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2 \approx 0.03215.$$

Additionally, this is the probability of **exactly three** ones. If you want three or more, you also need to add the probability of getting 4 ones and 5 ones:

$$P(X \geq 3) = \sum_{x = 3}^5 \left[\binom{5}{x}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{x}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{5-x} \right] \approx 0.03549.$$

You can use a calculator like [this one](https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial) to check those numbers.

Comment: My reasoning was: I get a one 3 times in a row. The probability is (1/6)^3. Then I can get a one in whatever roll. There are $\binom{5}{3}$ to get 3 ones out of 5 rolls. Since the events are mutually exclusive, (if I get 1,1,1 I can't get 1,1,2,1) I add them. Then, __since I want 3 or more ones__, I don't care what I obtain in the other rolls. Why you add the probability of getting 4 or 5 ones, instead of ignoring what you obtain in the other rolls?

Comment: @robertspierre To avoid double-counting. Consider the roll 1,1,1,1,5. With your method, you're counting that roll 4 times because there are 4 ways to form a triplet of ones using the 4 ones in this roll.

Comment: @Stef I didn't understand

Comment: @robertspierre When you write$$\binom{5}{3}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^3$$you're counting all ways of choosing 3 dice, set those to 1 and ignore the two other dice. Among all things that will be counted, there will be the result where you choose the first three dice, set them to 1, ignore the values of the last two dice, setting them for instance to 1 and 5, result 1,1,1,1,5; but you will also count, additionally, the result where you choose the first two dice and the fourth die, set them to 1, and ignore the values of the third and fifth dice, setting them to 1 and 5, result 1,1,1,1,5, etc.

Comment: ah sorry. Now I understand. So the outcomes with more than 3 ones are counted multiple times.

Comment: @Stef Thank you. Thank you very much.

Comment: @robertspierre Yes. The 25 combinations with exactly 4 ones will be counted 4 times each and the combination with 5 ones will be counted 10 times. You can check that in wzbillings's formula, if you add a factor 4 on the x=4 term, and a factor 10 on the x=5 term, you'll find the same wrong value 0.046 that you found with the formula $\binom 5 3 (1/6)^3$